# Skype-compatible Windows software without ads

Tags: windows, gratis, voip, skype

I am looking for a VOIP app:

- compatible with Skype: I use my Skype account, see my Skype friends and call them (at least voice; chat and video not really necessary)
- gratis
- no advertisements
- works on Windows

What I tried:

- Recent versions of the official Skype client (by Microsoft): Excessive ads
- Old version of the official Skype client: Not compatible anymore

Comment: A little late and not ideal, but [advertisments on Skype can be blocked](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-ads-in-skype-updated-for-recent-versions/), and the resulting thing complies all requirements and is spam-free.

Comment: @Alejandro: Great! Please post that as an answer, thanks :-)